# Abstrac syntax tree implementation

Tags: compiler-construction

I’m working on a compiler for mini c#. The symbol table is done, and all I know about next stage that I have to build an abstract syntax tree.
So my questions are :
1.  Why do I need an abstract syntax tree when I already have a symbol table which can hold much more information than the syntax tree. 
2.  What are the attributes an AST node should hold?
 Lastly, if anyone knows a book or any reference I could use, please let me know.

Comment: What are you calling a "*symbol table*"?

Comment: How can you retrieve a symbol table before the AST? It doesn't make sense. The symbol table is populated during analysis of the AST.

Answer (score 1):

1)
Well, the symbol table (ST) can hold only static informations about the symbols. But to collect those informations, one has to understand the syntactical position of symbols in an expression or command.

So, for example, if your lexical analyzer tells you it founds a "type" token, you don't have nothing to do in your ST. Next it can finds you an "identifier". So `int i;` can be the command. You need to put into your ST an integer variable. But if the sequence is `int i();`, you need to define your identifier `i` as a function that returns an int.

I'm quite confused how can you already have a ST without a AST, because that is how the ST is fulfilled.

2)
In general, an AST don't hold information about symbols. The very position of the symbols in the tree is its most valued information. So if you see something like:

```
int main(void)
{
  int i=0;
  if(i==0)
  {
    int i=1;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
  }
  printf("i=%d\n", i);
}
```

Because the position of the second `i` in the AST, bellow the tree, inside the "if", you can tell your ST to have 2 `i`'s, and that they are different variables. Something you can't guess beforehand, not until you creat a tree with all symbols.

Take care,
Beco

PS. Edited:
The best book I use:

Compilers: Principles, Techniques, & Tools with Gradiance (pkg) (2nd Edition)
by Alfred V. Aho, Monica S. Lam, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey D. Ullman
Publisher: Addison Wesley; 2 edition (October 15, 2007)
ISBN-10: 0321547985
ISBN-13: 978-0321547989